# Pymongo : insert_many + unique index

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to `insert_many()` documents in my collection. Some of them may have the same key/value pair (`screen_name` in my example) than existing documents inside the collection. I have a unique index set on this key, therefore I get an error.

```
my_collection.create_index("screen_name", unique = True)

my_collection.insert_one({"screen_name":"user1", "foobar":"lalala"})
# no problem

to_insert = [
    {"screen_name":"user1", "foobar":"foo"}, 
    {"screen_name":"user2", "foobar":"bar"}
]
my_collection.insert_many(to_insert)

# error : 
# File "C:\Program Files\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 331, in execute_command 
# raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
# 
# BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

I'd like to :

1. Not get an error
2. Not change the already existing documents (here `{"screen_name":"user1", "foobar":"lalala"}`)
3. Insert all the non-already existing documents (here, `{"screen_name":"user2", "foobar":"bar"}`)

---

**Edit :** As someone said in comment "this question is asking how to do a bulk insert and ignore unique-index errors, while still inserting the successful records. Thus it's not a duplicate with the question how do I do bulk insert". Please reopen it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One solution could be to use the `ordered` parameter of `insert_many` and set it to `False` (default is `True`):

```
my_collection.insert_many(to_insert, ordered=False)
```

[From the PyMongo documentation:](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many)

> *ordered* (optional): If `True` (the default) documents will be inserted
> on the server serially, in the order provided. If an error occurs all
> remaining inserts are aborted. If `False`, documents will be inserted on
> the server in arbitrary order, possibly in parallel, **and all document
> inserts will be attempted.**

Although, you would still have to handle an exception when all the documents couldn't be inserted.

Depending on your use-case, you could decide to either `pass`, log a warning, or inspect the exception.